# Qt Phonon with constantly updated QBuffer

Tags: qt4

I am looking for advanced working  example of Qt Phonon with constantly updated QBuffer (QIODevice)

Comment: I second this question. The existing documentation and examples need more especially when you have your own data source. Is this 4.7 rather than 4.8?

Comment: It is rather backend thing then phonon itself. As far as I know, delivered with Qt backends can't handle such device.

Comment: Forgot to add... If you're brave enough you could build phonon vlc backend, but probably you will have to replace phonon library with own build. Also you may use Qt Gstreamer bindings without phonon at all

Comment: Gstreamer is only for Linux , I need it for Windows

Comment: Can you please navigate me where can I learn about the issue.I didn't find any useful info neither in Qt books nor in Qt online documentation.

Comment: @LarisaBasov please use name tag when you're answering. There are binary packages of GStreamer for windows from OSSBuild http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/ I've integrated them with windows application without any problem